# How can i get parameter form IPN Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I use class PaypalIPN to check verified. I can check it with code insert database but i don't know how can i get parameter of IPN

```
<?php
require_once('PaypalIPN.php');

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$ipn = new PayPalIPN();

// Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
$ipn->useSandbox();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
$raw_post_data = '';
if ($verified) {
    //$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if($raw_post_data=='')
        $raw_post_data = '222';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (xtext) VALUES (".$raw_post_data.")";
}


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PayPal provides [documentation for all the IPN variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/).

For example, it shows that you can expect to get a "txn_type" parameter, which would provide a value that specifies what type of transaction the IPN is for.

If you want to get that value in your script you would use `$_POST['txn_type']`.

Not all IPNs will have all parameters shown in that document, so I like to populate expected data like this to avoid PHP warnings when a particular variable isn't included in the IPN...

```
$txn_type = !empty($_POST['txn_type']) ? $_POST['txn_type'] : '';
```